# Comparing data between rows within a table

Tags: t-sql

I have following table structure

```
table 1     
ID SOURCE_ID    NAME
1   1            A
2   1            B
3   2            B
4   2            C
5   2            A
```

i need to pick those names which are common across all SOURCE_ID , hence i expect names A and B as they are present in both the SOURCE_ID 1,2.

The following query gives me the expected output:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT NAME  
FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE1 B
WHERE A.NAME = B.NAME AND A.SOURCE_ID != B.SOURCE_ID
```

Now when the data in table changes to include a new record ID 6

---

```
table 1     

ID  SOURCE_ID   NAME
1   1             A
2   1             B
3   2             B
4   2             C
5   2             A
6   3             A
```

The name that is common in all three SOURCE_ID(1,2,3) IS A.

My query fails to return the correct output as new records are entered.

Please provide me a query that works correctly when new records are inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        SOURCE_ID INT,
        NAME VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1,'A'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1,'B'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2,'B'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2,'C'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2,'A'

--INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 3,'A'

;WITH DistinctCount AS (        
        SELECT  NAME,
                COUNT(DISTINCT SOURCE_ID) Cnt
        FROM    @Table
        GROUP BY    NAME
)
SELECT  *
FROM    DistinctCount
WHERE   Cnt = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SOURCE_ID) FROM @Table)
```

With the 6th insert commented out, should return A and B, with it included, should return A